# Scatterplot with different colors for each filtred dataset

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I am working on a project that tries to evaluate bus drivers driving efficiency. The data i am working with looks like this:

```
Driver     fvec_arpox_md
1          2561
2          1245
2          2315
2          1264
3          1256
3          1235
1          2145
2          3265
5          2121
9          1256
5          1785
46         1945
2          1261
3          1245
```

So i would like to do a scatterplot that shows fvec_aprox_md just for some specific drivers (for instance, drivers 1 and 2) and each dataset with a different color.

I have just started to learn R and so far i have just been able to get a plot like this:
[image: Scatterplot with all the data unfiltred and color gradient]

Also i added a filter that just shows on the console filtred data, but it does not affect the scatterplot. This is the code i have used:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
filter(Ruta268, num_conductor==4327)
b<-ggplot(Ruta268, aes(y=Ruta268$fvec_aprox_md, x=seq(1,length(Ruta268$fvec_aprox_md)), group=num_conductor, color=num_conductor))
b + geom_point() +
  geom_smooth()
```

Comment: If you do something like  `test <- filter(Ruta268, num_conductor==4327)` then `b<-ggplot(test, aes(y ... ` (note: generally, `ggplot` does not need the `dataset$...`, but only the column names ), the filter is going to work (also in a `dplyr` chain).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like to add a colour code for each driver, you need to add the `colour` argument into the aesthetics `aes()`. In `ggplot2`, whenever you want the function to refer to something within your data, you need to put it into `aes()`. When you just want to change an argument for the whole plot or within each `geom` layer, independent of your data, you can put an argument after the `aes()`, such as `ggplot(data, aes(x,y), colour = 'red')`.

This is the reason why your `geom_smooth()` does not work either. The `group` argument needs to be in the aesthetics as well for `geom_smooth()` to find the data and fit a smooth line for each of your drivers.

```
b<-ggplot(Ruta268,
          aes(y=Ruta268$fvec_aprox_md,
              x=seq(1,length(Ruta268$fvec_aprox_md),
              color=num_conductor,
              group=num_conductor
              )
          )
b + geom_point() +
    geom_smooth()
```

If you're new to R I strongly recommend this [open book](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/) written by the `tidyverse`developers to get you started more smoothly.

And if you only want to have a few drivers within your whole dataset, you should filter them beforehand as @s_t suggested and use it in `ggplot()` instead of `Ruta268`.

```
filtered.df <- Ruta268 %>%
              filter(num_conductor == 4327)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I start to understand a bit how this works. That open book you have recommenden me is just what i need, thanks a lot!!